During UDS diagnosis, the upper computer keeps sending can messages 0x7F&0x78
During UDS diagnosis, the upper computer keeps sending can messages 0x7F & 0x78. The fault is caused by the failure to access the DCM service for debugging. How can I solve this problem? Is it related to S3 and P2
Attempts to modify S3 were unsuccessful

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you mean that you are getting a Negative Response (SID = 0x7F) with the Negative Response Code "requestCorrectlyReceived-ResponsePending" (0x78)? If so, you probably need to wait. If not, you need to edit your question to give a lot more detail.
